# how to add thermal printer SDK to Ionic Project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, sdk, thermal-printer

I have developed an Ionic Project.I need to Print receipts from my app using thermal printer. The printer is connected to the LAN and my device is also connected to the same WIFI. I Have also got the printer SDK And a sample app.

How to integrate both so that i can print form my app?

Comment: check out the following plugins - https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer  https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer

Comment: Thanks for reply. The printer is not a bluetooth printer.it is connected Lan and my device is connected the same Lan..

Comment: the second link works with network printer

Comment: i used the plugin but i couldnt find the printer in the printer list..How to install driver of the printer in device or use printer SDK so that device could detect the printer..Thanks for help.

Comment: you gotta have printer service enabled on the device as this plugin just helps in invoking the service.

Comment: How to enable printer Service on the device? Printer Manufacture has got their Own SDK. Does this SDK will help to enable printer service?

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-add-a-printing-service-to-your-android-device-in-a-flash/

Comment: @Gandhi  network printer only for ios?

Comment: @shanthan katzer/cordova-plugin-printer plugin supports both android and ios

Comment: can we print by put ip address and port even in android?  cordova.plugins.printer.print(content, { printer: 'ipp://...' });